# setState not setting state variable React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to set state variable to response data from api call but unable to do so . I have division array in responseJson which i'm trying to set to divisions array in state. I'm getting the responseJson values on console.log but when i'm trying setState({...this.state,divisions:responseJson.division}) i'm not getting any data on console.

**state**

```
    this.state={
    token: data.token,
    role: data.role,
    userId: data.userId,
    organizationId: data.organizationId,
    organizationName: data.organization_name,
    workspacePP: false,
    workspaces: [],
    divisions:[],
    addWorkspace: null,
    isDivisionViewable:false,
    divisionName:null

};
```

**function addDivision**

```
 addDivision=()=> {

 const uri = `${APPURL}/workspace/division/create`;
 console.log('dddddd',this.state)
  fetch(uri, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.state.token}`
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
              workspace_id: this.state.workspaces[0].workspace_id,
              organization_id: this.state.organizationId,
              division:this.state.divisionName
        }),
    }).then((res)=>res.json()).then(responseJson=>{

          if(!responseJson.status){
            message.error(responseJson.error);
            return;
          }
          console.log('dddd',responseJson);

          this.setState({...this.state,divisions:responseJson.division})

    })
    console.log(this.state)//returns empty array
  }
```

**responseJson**

```
{status: true, division: Array(1), created_at: {…}, user: {…}}
created_at:
updated_at: ["2019-03-09 14:05:26"]
__proto__: Object
division: Array(1)
0: {id: 5, userid: "t863060h", workspace_id: "ROPHV6W", workspace_name: 
"workspace", created_at: "2019-03-09 13:39:31", …}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
status: true
user:
created_at: "2019-03-08 18:29:56"
email: "trycatchh@mail.com"
email_verification: 1
id: 1
loginStatus: 0
mobile_otp: 0
mobile_verification: 0
phone: "9632587410"
role: "Admin"
slug: ""
status: 2
team: null
uid: null
```

updated_at: "2019-03-08 18:29:56"
   userid: "t863060h"
   username: "tryy catchh"

**console.log(this.state)**

```
nName: "tryCatchh", …}
addWorkspace: true
divisionName: "dud"
**divisions**: Array(0)//no data
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
isDivisionViewable: true
organizationId: "finalids"
organizationName: "tryCatchh"
role: "Admin"
userId: "t863060h"
workspacePP: false
workspaces: [{…}]
```

**other funtction**

```
  showDivision=()=>{
        console.log('dddd',this.state.divisions);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SetState is asynchronous so To see updated state value you need to

Change

```
this.setState({...this.state,divisions:responseJson.division})
```

To

```
  this.setState({
       divisions:responseJson.division
  }, () => {
        console.log(this.state.divisions);//here you will get updated divisions state value
   });
```

Comment: @Hemadari Dasari Thanks for the answer it works for me now

Comment: @Hemadari Dasari i tried to use this divisions variable in other function by this.state.divisions but it returned null.

Comment: It won’t be able in other functions until the component is rendered

Comment: @ Hemadri Dasar I have edited the post can you check once

Answer (score 2):

Notice your setState is in **then** function, and will run after the API call response. Your console.log(this.state) will run immediately after calling the API.

if you want to see the final state after the API call, pass a callback func as the second parameter to setState like this:

```
this.setState({ divisions:responseJson.division }, () => console.log(this.state))
```

note: you don't need to destructure the state when calling setState, React does it for you already.

Comment: thanks for the answer ...  now i tried to use this divisions variable in other function by this.state.divisions but it returned null

Comment: the problem is when you use it. can you share the code?

Comment: @Mike3096 when do you call showDivision? it will be the same if you call that function immediately after api call, the response isn't there yet. and what is your use case

Comment: my case is i have to use divisions in render function

Comment: render function should be re-run when the state change, and will have the latest data. if it's still not working can you create a sample in codesandbox I can have a look